# Prove that the equation has at most 2 solutions

Tags: real-analysis

For any numbers a, b and and an even natural number n that the equation 
$$x^n+ax+b=0$$ has at most 2 solutions.

**My attempt:** $f'(x)=nx^{n-1}+a$, $n \text{ is even} \implies n-1 \text{ is odd} \implies f'(x) \text{ is strictly increasing}$.

Now I want to show that $f'(x)$ has exactly 1 root, so that I can apply Rolle's theorem to get the desired result. I think I need to use IVT, but which endpoints of the interval (c,d) should I take?

P.S. Is this still true if n is odd?

Comment: You mean at most two real solutions. The same question is here :
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1534686/show-xnaxb-0-has-most-two-solutions/1534704#1534704

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x^3-x$ has three roots.

To your other question, you don't need to show that $f'(x)$ has exactly one root, just that it can't have more than one (which is clear, since it is strictly increasing).  It is true, though, that it always has exactly one root...to see that note that $f'(x)$ tends to $-\infty$ if $x$ tends to $-\infty$ and $f'(x)$ tends to $+\infty$ if $x$ tends to $+\infty$.  More broadly, every odd degree polynomial has at least one real root.

Comment: N.B. the Q. states even exponent for the leading term.

Comment: @stochasticboy321  In the last line, the OP asks if it can be extended to odd $n$.

Comment: @lulu $f′(x)$ is strictly increasing, so it has at most 1 root (which is $x=\left(-\frac{a}{n}\right)^{1/(n-1)})$, so by Rolle's theorem $f(x)$ has at most 2 roots, correct?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x)=x^n+ax+b$$ then $$f(0)=b$$ so we get $$f'(x)=nx^{n-1}+a$$ so we have $$f'(x)\geq 0$$ if $$a\geq 0$$.
If $$a<0$$ so we obtain  $$f'(x)=0$$ if $$x=\left(-\frac{a}{n}\right)^{1/(n-1)}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: $f′(x)$ is strictly increasing, so it has at most 1 root (which is $x=\left(-\frac{a}{n}\right)^{1/(n-1)})$, so by Rolle's theorem $f(x)$ has at most 2 roots, correct?